# Margin before element with responsive width

Tags: html, css

I have list of some elements, that SHOULD looks like this:
[image: Grid]

1: Background can be different. Elements can have their own styles (such as border etc.).
(Elements are simplified on image/fiddle, everything that is not important omitted.)
2: All gray things should be responsive, so I using:

```
div.grey {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

3: All margins(black) should be 3px, so:

```
.grey {
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.grey:nth-child(8n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.grey:nth-child(n+9) {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

And I got:
[image: Got]

Margins are not included in percented width and as result, rows broken.

How to fix it?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/721k1gkz/)

Comment: What display property for .grey do you use? Do you float this elements?

Comment: @matcygan, question fixed, fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/721k1gkz/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want the boxes to be 12.5% width in order to fill 8 boxes in a line, plus fixed 3px margins around them. It'd be quite straight forward if we could include the margins in box-sizing since the boxes would be 12.5% everything included, instead we can use a border to get the same result, but since you've warned about the background should be visible from the margin, here is another approach using padding, box-sizing and nested divs.

```css
.grey {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  padding-left: 3px;   
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grey > div {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.grey:nth-child(n+9) {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.grey:nth-child(8n+1) {
  padding-left: 0;
}

/* Helper */
.wrapper {
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grey"><div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>14</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>15</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>16</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grey"><div>17</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Meow, background can be different on different pages. All elements already have borders, but this info was ommited in question.

Comment: @ShamilYakupov thanks for the clarification, can you use nested divs?

Comment: @ShamilYakupov ok, I've changed the answer. how about this way?

Comment: @ShamilYakupov yes, I've just did. Does it introduce any new problems?

Comment: Only a bit, first row element bigger than others. Anyway it's good variant. Any other ideas?

Comment: @ShamilYakupov yes, by 3 pixels which occured to me too, but I find it inevitable in this circumstances. I wish margin was included in border-box though, but it'd be same in that case too so Idk. I don't have a solution for that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use calc + inner block with negative margin-left

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="grey">1
        </div>
        <div class="grey">2
        </div>
        <div class="grey">3
        </div>
        <div class="grey">4
        </div>
        <div class="grey">5
        </div>
        <div class="grey">6
        </div>
        <div class="grey">7
        </div>
        <div class="grey">8
        </div>
        <div class="grey">9
        </div>
        <div class="grey">10
        </div>
        <div class="grey">11
        </div>
        <div class="grey">12
        </div>
        <div class="grey">13
        </div>
        <div class="grey">14
        </div>
        <div class="grey">15
        </div>
        <div class="grey">16
        </div>
        <div class="grey">17
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grey {
        float: left;
        width: calc(12.5% - 3px);
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .grey:nth-child(n+9) {
        margin-top: 3px;
    }

    /* Helper */
    .wrapper {
        background-color: black;
    }

    .wrapper .inner {
        margin-left: -3px;
    }

    .wrapper .inner:before, .wrapper .inner:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }

    .wrapper .inner:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

Here is working result - https://jsfiddle.net/itoriginal/721k1gkz/6/

Comment: I've edited my answer with link to fiddle. Is this what need?

Comment: Too bad that I didn't numerate elements on first image. No, there is should be 8 elements in a row and looks exactly like on first image.

Comment: Edited my answer. Is this result what you need?

Comment: Yes, I thought about use of calc, but its not supported on mobile devices.

Comment: In this case I think you should use this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32617194/3629287

Answer (score 0):

With `box-sizing` you can use a border around your grey elements instead of a margin, then the width will be calculated including the width of the border, and your floated elements' widths won't add up to more than that of the container:

```css
.grey {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 3px solid #000;
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
}
.grey:nth-child(-n+8) {
    border-top: 0; /* Remove top border from first 8 */
}
.grey:nth-child(8n+1) {
    border-left: 0; /* Remove left border from every 9th */
}
/* Helper */
 .wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}
.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grey">1</div>
    <div class="grey">2</div>
    <div class="grey">3</div>
    <div class="grey">4</div>
    <div class="grey">5</div>
    <div class="grey">6</div>
    <div class="grey">7</div>
    <div class="grey">8</div>
    <div class="grey">9</div>
    <div class="grey">10</div>
    <div class="grey">11</div>
    <div class="grey">12</div>
    <div class="grey">13</div>
    <div class="grey">14</div>
    <div class="grey">15</div>
    <div class="grey">16</div>
    <div class="grey">17</div>
    <div class="grey">17</div>
    <div class="grey">17</div>
    <div class="grey">17</div>
</div>
```

Note: See [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility) for `box-sizing`, use browser prefixes.

Comment: Meow, background can be different on different pages. All elements already have borders, but this info was ommited in question.

Comment: Then either define your margin in percentage or use `calc` and forfeit browser support.